# Executing python script which depends on numpy and cv2

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm executing python script in AWS lambda and I want to use numpy and cv2 in that python script. Is there a way to include numpy and cv2 into lambda zip package?

Answer (score 0):

this blog post seems to answer your question.

[python on aws lambda](http://willyg302.github.io/blog/posts/2015-03-29-python-on-aws-lambda/)

Namely, its about creating a virtualenv and executing the python code from within that context.

Comment: fyi...aws lambda now natively supports python.